# Inequality of 2 positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Good day,

Suppose I have 2 positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a\lt b$. I could write $a^2 \lt b^2$ since both are positive, but I could also write $0 \lt (b-a)^2$. Expanding the second inequality gives $0 \lt (b^2 -2ab + a^2)$. This however is not the same as the first inequality, which is $0 \lt (b^2 - a^2)$. I know I must have made a mistake somewhere, but I can't seem to find the error. Any help would be most appreciated.

Best wishes

Comment: There's no mistake. Both inequalities are true. Furthermore the second inequality is true even if $b<a$: it just means a non-zero square is always positive.

Comment: @Bernard : Thanks! I don't know why but I was somehow under the impression both inequalities had to be the same. Thanks for clearing this up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: it is $$0<(b-a)^2<b^2-a^2$$ since $$b^2+a^2-2ab\le b^2-a^2$$ since $$2a^2-2ab<0$$ since $$2a(a-b)\le 0$$ since $$a,b>0$$ and $$ a<b$$